# How to place block diagram into frame

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can somebody help me put this block diagram into this frame. I know there are a lot of questions about this specific diagram but I do have a project and I need your help. [image: So this top diagram won't fit into this top frame, the second is alright]

Comment: The first diagram can't fit into the first frame, the second one is okay.Is there a code to lift up this diagram

Comment: Hi, welcome. There might be several methods of doing that, depending on how you made it in the first place. Possibly you can do `\begin{scope}[shift={(1cm,4cm)}] <the diagram code> \end{scope}` (obviously changing those lengths to whatever is appropriate), but it would really make it easier to give a reliable answer if you showed us the code for that diagram, and not just an image.

Comment: This is a repetition of [this previous post of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543376/194703). You will have much better chances of getting an answer if you post a minimal compilable example that shows what you have. Otherwise, as mentioned by @TorbjørnT., it is next-to-impossible to write a reliable answer. So please, instead of posting these screen shots, post codes, and you will almost certainly get a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. It works now. I would have posted the code but somebody might copy and use it and I don't want that to happen ;)

Comment: @myname Thought you might say that, honestly, the instructor of whatever course you're taking should consider making a rule saying that asking questions here are not allowed ... That said, a way of asking a question would be to make the code more general: Remove the bottom frame and block diagram. Remove everything except one or two blocks from the top diagram. Remove the styles, and replace the text,  so you're  left with a just couple of rectangles with dummy text, offset from the top frame.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Considering the situation because of the virus, all we have is this page and some literature which is not enough. You will probbaly find more of this content from my coleagues. We have a rule, nobody can have the same code and that makes it more stressfull. Thank you for your help again.